# Is there the way to callback from Java application to Rails application?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

I am studying Rails.

I want to use a callback method from java to Rails(controller & model).

I tried a Embedding way using 'ScriptingContainer' in Java. However, It makes new instance.

I think I need to get a controller(& model) instance of the running Rails application to use a callback method.

Is it possible ?? If it is possible, please help me to know the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use webservice ..which is made to handle this kind of scenarios where an application on one technology communicates with other having other technology.....most usual example i can give is using *facebook signup* and **getting friends list** from facebook,where `facebook(php)` communicates with other applications made on `java,rails,Dotnet` etc....so all you need is to setup webservice..which is just a method mapped to hande/serve a particular request....

@JYChoi ..Netbeans is an IDE which provides a convinient environment for writing and maintaining JAVA code...yes irrespective of any IDE...you can write a method in your java applicaton such as send_request_to_rails using http library(its a guess) and in rails you can write get_request_from_java to handle request coming from outside the applicaton and communicate using json(most reliable),refer this that uses Jruby (http://jruby.org/) which is meant for the purpose of using java along with ruby on rails ,precisely ruby......https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_117_invoke_a_jax

Comment: Thank you.. I have one question. Do you mean that I can use Webservice like NetBeans?

Comment: added more nfo @JYChoi